# ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
SELECT 
  FIRST_NAME, 
  MIDDLE_NAME, 
  LAST_NAME, 
  FIRST_NAME+''+ COALESCE(MIDDLE_NAME,'')+''+LAST_NAME AS PO_NAME 
FROM OFFICER
```

running this query fires as error ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge words like in php but try this one:

```sql
SELECT
    FIRST_NAME,
    MIDDLE_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    CONCAT( FIRST_NAME, ' ', COALESCE ( MIDDLE_NAME, ' ' ), ' ', LAST_NAME ) AS PO_NAME 
FROM
    OFFICER
```

For more details see: [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)